# Google Analytics: Uncaught ReferenceError: _gat is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

### "_gat is not defined" error on page load

Tried suggestions from: [Uncaught ReferenceError: _gaq is not defined (Google Analytics)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401894/uncaught-referenceerror-gaq-is-not-defined-google-analytics) but didn't help.

Here is my initial code snippet:

```
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})(); 

var pageTracker pageTracker = _gat._createTracker('UA-xxxxxxxx-1'); 

<button onclick="pageTracker._setCustomVar(1,'customvar1', 'value', 3); 
pageTracker._trackPageview();">Fire</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution (adding delay):

```
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})(); 

var pageTracker; 
setTimeout(function(){
    pageTracker = _gat._createTracker('UA-xxxxxxxx-1'); 
    pageTracker._initData(); 
}, 1000); 

<button onclick="pageTracker._setCustomVar(1,'customvar1', 'value', 3); 
pageTracker._trackPageview();">Fire</button>
```

In my tests, I found that 1 second is a good delay period - anything less than 1 second yielded a much higher possibility of getting *_gat undefined* error.

Comment: This makes no sense. You're going to be calling `pageTracker._setCustomVar(...)` before `pageTracker` is initialized with a value. Even if this would work, using an arbitrary delay is a poor solution.

Comment: my bad. the example of customvar was just to illustrate an action. The main issue was "_gat._createTracker" on page load that results in undefined error, because the ga script hasn't finished loading yet

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but I was able to fix my "_gat is not defined" error by including the first snippet inside the `<head>` tag.  Then including the second snippet anywhere in the body on the page I want to track.

So this goes in the `<head`:

```
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

And this on any page you want to track:

```
pageTracker = _gat._createTracker('UA-xxxxxxxx-1'); 
pageTracker._trackPageview();
```